# mmap gets corrupted, is malloc overriding elements on memory

Tags: c++, linux, virtual, mmap

I've been having random problems in the data files, those data files are accessed for read only using mmap (they are big), and I've been trying to locate the source of the error, what I noticed is that the files get corrupted at the end with random data from whatever is executing at that moment, (extracts from the console, some logs that are been executed by other programs, etc.). Today, my program crashed again, but this time I noticed that the corrupted file is only open as read-only, which does not make sense. How is that a file gets corrupted if it was open using this:

```
FILE _pFile = ::open(fileName, O_RDONLY);
char* _addr = reinterpret_cast<char *>(mmap(NULL, fileLenRequired, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | (shared?MAP_SHARED:MAP_PRIVATE) | MAP_POPULATE , _pFile, offset));
```

Reading some other questions makes me think that mmap is not "protected" and it might be overridden/overlapped by malloc calls, how do I prevent this?

By the way, I thought this was caused by a memory leak, or a wrong pointer, therefore I did a full check using valgrind and fixed several problems, but the files keep corrupting from time to time.

Comment: If your program *actually* sees data from *other programs*, your OS or machine are broken. Since you're running Linux, I suspect your diagnosis is incorrect.

Comment: This is happening not only in my machine, the production server crashes every 2 days or so, I don't see a high consumption and I don't see any steps to reproduce this, it just crashes doing the normal work.

Comment: I'd be inclined to suspect hardware problems, given your description - the code you showed looks completely innocent to me.  There should not be any such thing as interference between malloc and mmap.  Start with a memory test.  Or one of the standard torture tests like compiling gcc from source.

Comment: Agree with you @NateEldredge I don't think this is causing the issue, but I'm wondering how memory claimed by mmap could be overridden, and  how is that corruption is written to a file that is opened as read-only?

Comment: @Cross: In theory, it cannot.  That is why I suspect that the code you are looking at doesn't have anything to do with the actual problem.

Comment: Are you sure there is not another program using this file ? (or another part of your programm) ? You can check with `lsof` for example

Comment: @Olaf, care to elaborate? in what sense this is not? using the open or fopen does not change the question/answers or anything, for the rest of it, it's C code.

Comment: In the sense of the C standard?! If you do not see that instantly, you never should add the C tag, because you have no idea about C. Try compiling this as-is with a C compiler!

Comment: I've changed the tag, but that does not change anything in the problem @olaf, thanks for pointing that out. do you think the reinterpret or the ::open will change the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Finally I discovered what was wrong with this, the problem was not the mapped files, Originally I thought the system was crashing because the files somehow got corrupted, what I found is that the crash happened first and then any opened file gets corrupted with trash. The problem is that it was really hard to reproduce and only occurred in a production server, I'd to crack my head to figure out what was wrong with this.

Thanks to everyone for taking the time to read and try to suggest options, at least this served to check if I was not doing something clearly wrong in my code.